NuxtJS + keycloak-js: frontend doesn't render the correct value
I have a Nuxt3 app which I want to secure with Keycloak.
For the integration, I use the keycloak-js library, which is defined as a plugin:
plugins/keycloak.client.ts
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
import type {KeycloakConfig} from 'keycloak-js';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
    const initOptions: KeycloakConfig = {
        url: runtimeConfig.public.KEYCLOAK_URL!,
        realm: runtimeConfig.public.KEYCLOAK_REALM!,
        clientId: runtimeConfig.public.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID!,
    };

    const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions);

    nuxtApp.$keycloak = keycloak;
    keycloak
        .init({
            onLoad: 'check-sso',
        });

    console.log('KeyCloak Plugin Loaded: ', nuxtApp.$keycloak);
});

The console logs this correctly.
For test purposes, I have a simple app.vue:
app.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
const keycloak: Keycloak = useNuxtApp()['$keycloak'] as Keycloak
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      Authenticated?
      {{keycloak.authenticated}}
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button @click="keycloak.login()">Login via Keycloak</button>
    <button @click="keycloak.logout()">Logout from Keycloak</button>
  </div>
</template>

Logging in and out works and the log of the keycloak object shows the correct value.
This page always displays false when I load it, even if authenticated shows up as true in the console.
However, if I do a small change in the code and the app hot-reloads, the correct value is shown (until the next refresh).
What's more, if I do:
console.log(keycloak);
console.log(keycloak.authenticated);

The log of the complete object will show the value to be true, but the second log will show false.
I should add that Nuxt is quite new for me. With my half-knowledge, I tried:

Different ways to import,
Putting the code in onBeforeMount(),
Declaring keycloak as a ref,
Putting a watch on keycloak

SSR is disabled in the nuxt.config.ts.
I'm fresh out of ideas.
What am I missing?

keycloak.init returns a Promise. keycloak.authenticated is read before the keycloak instance is initiated. Furthermore, keycloak.authenticated is not reactive, thus mutating its value will not reflect in the template.
Method 1
<script setup lang="ts">
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
const keycloak: Keycloak = useNuxtApp()['$keycloak'] as Keycloak
const authenticated = ref(false)

keycloak.onReady = (v: boolean) => { authenticated.value = v }

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      Authenticated?
      {{authenticated}}
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button @click="keycloak.login()">Login via Keycloak</button>
    <button @click="keycloak.logout()">Logout from Keycloak</button>
  </div>
</template>


Method 2
await the initialization of keycloak in nuxt plugin
export default defineNuxtPlugin({
  name: 'keycloak',
  order: 0,
  async setup() {
    await keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso' })
  },
})


